# Overriding hashcode and equals to enforce all instances are the same

Tags: java

```
class Dog {
    private int variableA;
    private int variableB;
    private int variableC;
    public Dog(int A, int B, int C) {
        variableA = A;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;

        if (o instanceof Dog)
            return true;

        return false;
    }


Set<Dog> dogSet = new HashSet<>();
dogSet.add(new Dog(1,2,3))
dogSet.add(new Dog(2,3,4))
```

I want to make sure that in `dogSet` there is only one instance of Dog

I believe my `hashCode()` and `equals()` achieve that. And is it the best practice the way i've implemented?

EDIT
there will be a multiple types of dog and Dog is actually an interface

```
public interface Dog
public class ShortDog extends Dog
public class BigDog extends Dog
public class OnlyOneDog extends Dog
...
```

and there is actually a class called `DogHouse` where this HashSet exists

```
public class DogHouse
    private Set<Dog> dogSet = new HashSet<>();
```

we can have many instance of Dog (of their subtypes), but i want to make sure that dogSet is unique of its type for `OnlyOneDog` and I was going to achieve that with hashcode and equals

I was going to override hashcode + equals in `OnlyOneDog`. this is a special case for OnlyOneDog

is there a better way?

Comment: You can just `return o instanceof Dog;`. That will cover your first condition and fallback `false`.

Comment: `hashCode` should be a hash function, it should depend some/all members to get a integer. This is just a performance thing.

Comment: What is [the real problem](http://xyproblem.info/) you're solving? Just curious. Your approach is likely to work, but it breaks the `Dog` class in multiple important ways.

Comment: Yes it will achieve that, so long as your program is single threaded.  It's not thread safe.  And this is far from best practice.  You need to read up on implementations of the singleton pattern - it seems that this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So you're going to lose either one set of your data, `1, 2, 3` or `2, 3, 4` (the latter, as written)?  Is that ok? - I feel the same as @9000.  I'd like to understand what you're really trying to do. - I've been doing this a long time, and this smells like something you'd  never want to do.

Comment: If you want to have just a single object – use an enum.

Comment: That meats your need, But emm, But I think that there would be a better solution to your issue. I agree with @DawoodibnKareem I think you might be thinking of a singleton container??

Comment: hello everyone, ive edited the post. let me know if that clear my intention up

Comment: @Cubimon but since im making equals to be the same as all instance, shouldnt hashcode not be dependent upon any members?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem im not looking for Singleton as it is okay to have many instnaces. But when I am to add into the HashSet in DogHouse, i only want of OnlyOneDog

Comment: @ealeon why do you want all dogs to be the same? You could do something like @Sotirios Delimanolis said and check the types for equality, but then you can't compare if two dogs are the same. I would rather implement your own `AddDog` method in `DogHouse` and check if a dog is already in the dog house. A simple member like `private Dog dog;` would be enough, and a `null` check to determine if the doghouse is empty.